# Listview Rendering Issue with jQuery Mobile 1.3.x and ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Having an issue with jQuery Mobile 1.3.x listviews rendering incorrectly on Internet Explorer 9/10 and IE 8 phone.  It renders correctly on Chrome, Safari, Safari on iOS and jQuery Mobile 1.2.1 on IE 9/10.  I'm running VS 2012, C#, MVC and Razor on Win7.

To reproduce with VS 2012 generate a ASP.NET MVC 4 mobile project with Razor and then upgrade to jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 or 1.3.1 with NuGet.

This code on the home page is rendered with extra space between the list items and bullets on the left border:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Navigation</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</ul>
```

Before upgrade:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47974701/Capture%20B4.PNG

After upgrade to 1.3.0 jQuery Mobile:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47974701/Capture%20After.PNG

Comment: Which jQuery version are using? For JQM 1.3 it's recommended to use 1.8.2 or higher.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.1, jQuery UI 1.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the script blocks to the HEAD section fixes this.  It is not ideal for other reasons (it is at the bottom of the page for performance/optimization reasons), but it fixes the issue with IE not initializing properly.

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script>
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        });
    </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
</head>
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!  Is disabling Ajax required?  I'd like to keep the slick page transitions if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't be requried.  This is the default script rendered as part of the project template (for MVC4 Mobile template in Visual Studio).